# VB Export Access to Mysql fails on currencies format

Tags: mysql, vba, odbc, ms-access-2003

The following VBA script on Access 2003 exports all tables and data to MySQL.
Everything works except for currencies data, they are converted into Integers instead of floats. Floats are correctly exported.

In Access 2003

```
price : 1,22 € (currency format)
VAT : 1,115 (float)
```

becomes in mysql:

```
price : 1
VAT : 1.115
```

Here is the script:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Détail_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub export_mysql_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_export_mysql_Click

        Dim sTblNm As String
        Dim sTypExprt As String
        Dim sCnxnStr As String, vStTime As Variant
        Dim db As Database, tbldef As DAO.TableDef

        On Error GoTo ExportTbls_Error

        sTypExprt = "ODBC"
        'sCnxnStr = "ODBC;DSN=DSNname;UID=userOnServer;PWD=pwdOnServer"
        sCnxnStr = "ODBC;DSN=exporteau;UID=exporteau;PWD=xxxxxxxxxxx" 'Create the connection string
        vStTime = Timer
        Application.Echo False, "Visual Basic code is executing."

        Set db = CurrentDb()

        For Each tbldef In db.TableDefs
        Debug.Print tbldef.Name
        sTblNm = tbldef.Name
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, sTypExprt, sCnxnStr, acTable, sTblNm, sTblNm
        Next tbldef

        MsgBox "Exportation terminée"
        On Error GoTo 0
SmoothExit_ExportTbls:
        Set db = Nothing
        Application.Echo True
        Exit Sub

ExportTbls_Error:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ExportTblsODST"
        Resume SmoothExit_ExportTbls

Exit_export_mysql_Click:
            Exit Sub

Err_export_mysql_Click:
            MsgBox Err.Description
            Resume Exit_export_mysql_Click

End Sub

Private Sub export_mysql_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access 2002 uses the system regional settings for currencies.

Once there were set to separate decimals with `.` instead of `,` I got my numbers.